Why doesn't my Azure function show in the Azure Portal?
I have a function that auto-increments a value in a cosmosdb. I can check by going to the website that fetches this value and see that it is growing: Universal Time Units (TU): [14010].  So I know that the function is executing. However, the function does show that it is executing anywhere.

It is clearly running. Why can't I get an execution here? Does this chart mean something other that what I think it means?
The deployment clearly shows that it register my functions in the code and deployed them

however, it then says 0 functions loaded. Again, I can confirm that the function is running as I can go to the website and see the value updating.
Furthermore, the file tab shows that many files aren't there:

Again, the files must be there because otherwise the function would crash and not update the value. It would fail when importing them.
Lastly, when I try to query in application insights, I can't see any of the traces that would be there if the application were running:
traces
| order by timestamp desc
| limit 50

Returns no values. There are system logs:
4/27/2024, 6:48:52.944 PM
No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
4/27/2024, 6:48:52.942 PM
Generating 0 job function(s)
4/27/2024, 6:48:52.942 PM
0 functions loaded
4/27/2024, 6:48:52.941 PM
A function allow list has been specified, excluding all but the following functions: [resolveActionEvents, actionResolverTimer, ututimer]
4/27/2024, 6:48:52.941 PM
1 functions found (Custom)
4/27/2024, 6:48:52.941 PM
Reading functions metadata (Custom)
4/27/2024, 6:48:52.938 PM
Loading functions metadata

But none of the logs from the function that I can confirm is running. I need to use the logs in some of the other functions that I'm unable to confirm elsewhere. What is the correct way to confirm the execution of the functions?

Note that I was able to find a way to get the logs, I posted that solution in a GH issue. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1262#issuecomment-2119241515


Why can't I get an execution here?I can't see any of the traces that would be there if the application were running.

The above issue might that there could be a delay or a configuration issue causing the portal not to recognize the deployed function correctly.

Check the function app environment variables in portal, application insights configured correctly or not.
Restart the function app and then redeploy the functions once.

I have created Http trigger and timer trigger functions with runtime stack python.
Check the logging configuration and parameters like below code:
Function code:
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 */5 * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=False,
            use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')


I have successfully deployed the functions into portal and able to ran the functions in portal as well.
Check the below for successful execution count:


I am able to get the execution logs in application insights. check below:
Output:


Check the environment variables in function app configuration like below:


Thanks for this. I notice that all of the docs and tutorials specify the http or timer function, not the eventhub function. This is probably because it's easier to test and requires less supplemental. If you notice in my example above I have a timer function that I know is working fine because I can see the autoincremented value in the timer. It won't run the EH functions and I can't find a place where I can see a log showing what is wrong.
